# How to iterate the rows of a DataFrame as Series in Pandas?

Tags: loops, pandas, dataframe, series

How can I iterate over rows in a `DataFrame`? For some reason `iterrows()` is returning tuples rather than `Series`. I also understand that this is not an efficient way of using Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I iterate over rows in a DataFrame? For some reason iterrows() is returning tuples rather than Series.

The second entry in the tuple is a Series:

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4), 'b': range(2, 6)})

In [10]: for r in df.iterrows():
    print r[1], type(r[1])
   ....:     
a    0
b    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
a    1
b    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
a    2
b    4
Name: 2, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
a    3
b    5
Name: 3, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

> I also understand that this is not an efficient way of using Pandas.

That is true, in general, but the question is a bit too general. You'll need to specify why you're trying to iterate over the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2])

for i in s: 
    print (i)
0
1
2
```

`DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[4,5,8]})
print (df)
   a  b
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  8

for i,s in df.iterrows():
    print (s)

a    0
b    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
a    1
b    5
Name: 1, dtype: int64
a    2
b    8
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```